# Trouble running Eclipse for the first time on Mac

Tags: java, eclipse, macos, java-8, force.com

I am trying to install Eclipse for the first time  on my Mac in order to run the Force.com IDE.

The following are details of the JDK and Eclipse version that I've installed.

- I currently have Java 8 Update 181 installed on my Mac. I've installed the JDK, 64 bit.
- I am trying to install the Eclipse Neon 64 bit for Mac OSX, as this is the version that works with the Force.com IDE.
- The error that I receive when attempting to open Eclipse is below. It directs me to an error log in the workspace where my projects should be saved. Note that I do not currently have any projects, as I've been unable to proceed past this step. [An error has occurred: See the log file
  /Users/lexakoenig/Documents/workspace1/.metadata/.log.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eSwuH.png)
- When I navigate to the workspaces folder, there are no files, not even an error log as the message indicates.

Has anyone experienced this issue or have a resolution? I've tried quite a few troubleshooting steps, but none of them have worked, especially because there are no files in the workspace folder that the error log indicates.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, files starting with `.` are hidden by default. Are you sure the file isn't there, but hidden?

Comment: From a teminal, you can list hidden files with ls -a

Comment: for older pc installs you would need to point eclipse to java, by editing `.ini` file. not sure if this is the same

Comment: The file and directory are definitely there, as already mentioned they are hidden.  Press Cmd + Shift + . in Finder to reveal hidden files.

Comment: ThanksI I found the hidden file and I think the issue is with pointing eclipse to the correct Java version, as @mavriksc said. This error is repeatedly in the log file: "org.eclipse.e4.core.di.InjectionException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError".

Does anyone know how I can update the eclipse.ini file to point to the correct version? I found this article [link](https://wiki.eclipse.org/Eclipse.ini#-vm_value:_Mac_OS_X_Example), which is helpful. But I'm not familiar with terminal on Mac and could use more specific instructions as how to edit the .ini.

Comment: so you will need to find the folder where java is on the system as mentioned in the link. then add a line near the top `-vm /path/to/java/bin`  where it's the actual path you found to the java binary.

Comment: @mavriksc - I've been able to edit the eclipse.ini file directly by adding "-vm /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_181.jdk/Contents/Home/bin" above the -vmargs line. This ends up being in the middle of the eclipse.ini file, but I'm still getting the error.

Comment: what is the class it's saying it can't find